# Using VDM Brushes procedurally in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, displacement, vector-mapping, brushes

I am fascinated by the new possibilities to use VDM Brushes in Blender. I used the VDM Baker Addon to generate a VDM Texture.
I thought it might be interesting to use these in Geometry Nodes, to scatter points on a mesh and "brush" onto the mesh where the points are.
I quickly realized that my very limited understanding of how brushes work (and Math in geonodes) makes it more complicated than I thought.

My idea was that I could instance some grids with the VDM Image Texture onto the Mesh, snap them to the surface, transfer the vector colors from the grids to the mesh, and then displace by adding/multiplying/rotating(???) these vectors to the normal of the mesh.

I used this Tutorial by Default Cube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yy7raaJuYE to place the grids onto the mesh.

Here is my nodegroup:

[image: My Nodegroup]

[image: The Nodegroup to get UVs to where the points are]

I will spare you with what the results look like, it obviously didn't work with any combination of Rotating the VDM with the Normal or vice versa.

It SHOULD look something like this:

[Scattered points on Mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKZjQ.jpg)

[image: Displacement based on VDM Texture on every point (faked by doing it manually in Sculpt mode)]

If anyone with actual knowledge has any suggestions how to do it, I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image: Node setup]

Here is node setup example of scattering VDM from points.

Comment: Thank you so much, Higgsas! I will study this node setup and hopefully get through how it works! This is great. 
Also, offtopic, I really love your Nodegroup Tool Pack!
Thanks again